# Update statement where condtion is neglected

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, where-clause

When I invoke this procedure, it updates all rows in the table, and `where` condition is ignored:

```
PROCEDURE update_sto_status (REQUEST_NUMBER     IN VARCHAR2,
                                     SHIPMENT_NUMBERS   IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE apps.table1 OH
    SET OH.comments = SHIPMENT_NUMBERS
    WHERE OH.REQUEST_NUMBER = :REQUEST_NUMBER;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give the parameters of your procedure other names than the columns in the table, otherwise they become ambiguous.

Basically, in expression:

```
WHERE OH.REQUEST_NUMBER = REQUEST_NUMBER
```

The `REQUEST_NUMBER` at the right side of the equality is understood at the column name, not as the parameter. This condition is always true, and you end up with every record begin updated.

```
PROCEDURE update_sto_status (
    P_REQUEST_NUMBER   IN VARCHAR2,
    P_SHIPMENT_NUMBERS IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE apps.table1
    SET comments = P_SHIPMENT_NUMBERS
    WHERE request_number = P_REQUEST_NUMBER;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

When there's a collision between PL/SQL variable or parameter names and column names in a table the compiler *always* favors the column name in an SQL statement. In this case you've named your parameter `REQUEST_NUMBER`, which is the same as the column named `REQUEST_NUMBER`. So your statement is equivalent to

```
PROCEDURE update_sto_status (REQUEST_NUMBER     IN VARCHAR2,
                             SHIPMENT_NUMBERS   IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE apps.table1 OH
    SET OH.comments = SHIPMENT_NUMBERS
    WHERE OH.REQUEST_NUMBER = OH.REQUEST_NUMBER;
END;
```

The comparison above is always true, so every row is updated.

Solution: prefix parameters with `pin` for input parameters, `pout` for output parameters,  and `pio` for input/output parameters. Then your procedure becomes

```
PROCEDURE update_sto_status (pinREQUEST_NUMBER     IN VARCHAR2,
                             pinSHIPMENT_NUMBERS   IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE apps.table1 OH
    SET OH.comments = pinSHIPMENT_NUMBERS
    WHERE OH.REQUEST_NUMBER = pinREQUEST_NUMBER;
END;
```

and you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

try avoid `:`

```
  PROCEDURE update_sto_status (REQUEST_NUMBER     IN VARCHAR2,
                                 SHIPMENT_NUMBERS   IN VARCHAR2)
  IS
 BEGIN
   UPDATE apps.table1 OH
   SET OH.comments = SHIPMENT_NUMBERS
   WHERE OH.REQUEST_NUMBER = REQUEST_NUMBER;
 END;
```

Comment: what should i use instead ?

Comment: try the procedure without `:`  just  REQUEST_NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

*Always alias everything.*

```
PROCEDURE update_sto_status (REQUEST_NUMBER     IN VARCHAR2,
                                 SHIPMENT_NUMBERS   IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE apps.table1 OH
    SET OH.comments = update_sto_status.SHIPMENT_NUMBERS
    WHERE OH.REQUEST_NUMBER = update_sto_status.REQUEST_NUMBER;
END;
```